# Looking for words in a dataframe column that begin with "#" for each row, then adding them to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column called "Tweets".  I want to extract all the hashtagged words and put then in a new column.
Here's the code I tried:

```
for row in df.split(' '):
    for word in row:
        if word.startswith('#'):
            return row
     else: 
        return np.nan
```

Problem is it only returns one hashtag per row.  So if a row has "#word1 and #word2" it only returns "#word1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at pandas' string functions like [`extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with regex. Example:

```
tweets = ["lorem ipsum #hashtag01 #hashtag02 #another_one",
         "#one ipsum #two lorem #some_more"]

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=["tweets"])
df.tweets.str.extractall(r"(#\w+)").unstack()
```

The `(#\w+)` catches all strings as groups that start with `#` and have one or many consequent word characters `\w+`. `unstack()` restructures the columns appropriately.

[OUT]

```
match   0           1           2
0       #hashtag01  #hashtag02  #another_one
1       #one        #two        #some_more
```

If you want to extract all hashtags to **one single** column and are sure that hashtags are always separated by a space (like your example suggests), then you can use this line of code:

```
df["hashtags"] = df.tweets.apply(lambda x: [x for x in x.split(" ") if x.startswith("#")])
```

[OUT]

```
0    [#hashtag01, #hashtag02, #another_one]
1                  [#one, #two, #some_more]
```

Comment: how would I then combine them into a list so that its a single column  with row value [#hashtag01, #hashtag02, #anotherone]

Comment: I have added the code for the second option according to your question. You simply create a new column in your dataframe with the results of the `apply()` function.